# Must every left inverse function of a linear transformation be a linear transformation again?

Tags: linear-algebra, functions, linear-transformations, inverse

I just come up with a question that I usually ignore. Let $T:V\longrightarrow W$ be a linear transformation. Then $T$ may or may not have a left inverse (right, resp.). But if $T$ has a left inverse (right, resp.) $f$, then must $f$ be a linear transformation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Take $T\colon\mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow\mathbb R$ defined by $T(x,y)=x+y$. Define $f\colon\mathbb{R}\longrightarrow\mathbb{R}^2$ by $f(x)=(x+1,-1)$. Then $f$ is not linear, but $(\forall x\in\mathbb{R}):T\bigl(f(x)\bigr)=x$, which means that $f$ is a right inverse of $T$.

Comment: As for left inverse, $T:\Bbb R\to \Bbb R^2$ given by $T(x) = (x, 0)$ and $f:\Bbb R^2 \to \Bbb R$ given by $f(x, y) = x + xy^2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: @Arthur Thanks for the edit.

Comment: @Arthur How do you discover this counterexample? So complicated! I'm interested to learn.

Comment: @Eric I suspect that he just added to $x$ a non-linear term which is $0$ whenever $y$ is $0$. Another possibility would have been $x+\sin y$.

Comment: @Eric Jose is correct. We want a left inverse of $T$, so the $x$-axis must be mapped to $\Bbb R$. The $x$ in my definition of $f$ does that. Apart from that, I just have to add something which 1) is not linear, and 2) doesn't ruin the inverse property. That means that the second term must evaluate to $0$ on the $x$ axis, and apart form that it just has to be non-linear. $xy^2$ works, as does $\sin(y)$, or even something discontinuous, like $0$ when $y$ is rational and $1$ when $y$ is irrational.